# Backend token authorization with multiple social logins

Tags: flutter, rust, architecture, backend, google-signin

I'm building an application which has a backend where I want to authenticate and authorize users.
So far I've built a custom signup, and am using a JWT token alongside a REFRESH token to authorize users to my protected API routes.

Now a new requirement appeared where I am to use social logins (like google) and I believe I understand how this can be achieved architecture-wise.

On the frontend, authenticating on google returns a JWT that can be decoded through a public key. At this point and time, calling my custom route to serve each of the integrations, example {api}/auth/google, will "exchange", given a valid google jwt, for my own jwt and refresh token which allows access to my API. From this point on, having a valid jwt and refresh token everything functions as a normal user would.

At this point and time what should I do with the google sign-in jwt? It has an expiration time (I believe of an hour), am I supposed to renew it once it expires? If so, why? What are the pros of supporting this? Am I missing something?

Also, does the auth "architecture" make sense?

This might be useful: I'm not using firebase authentication, for this auth flow I'm using rust, redis for token maintenance and mongodb will store the user data.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth.

Comment: I had read this before, but the document's information stops after I create the user on my backend. My idea was how to treat this integration afterwards. Should I maintain my token as the sole authorization point of my protected api endpoints? Should a google token be enough to access them? Those are the questions. Thank you for your attention

Comment: I suggest first calling the Google API; upon successful completion, you can then proceed to call your backend API, providing the Google API credentials but generating a random password. This way, you can create a JWT token without Expiration